# Tangent Spaces & Definition of Differentiation

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds

1. What is meant by definition when we talk about the $c:(-\epsilon,\epsilon)\rightarrow M$ is that an interval on the curve?
2. In differential geometry what is the difference between

$D_{c(t)}$,

$Df_{x}$ & $df_{x}$

$dF_{c(t)}(C'(t))$

for given surface $f$?

[image]

Comment: the $(-\epsilon, \epsilon)$ is just the domain of the curve. The equivalence class of curves with matching tangents can be taken to define the "tangent vector", or you can use derivations, or contravariant vectors...